# Is it possible to stop one video on a page when another is clicked?

Tags: javascript, video

I have a very simple page that we are using to archive prior videos. I use Foundation 5 and have set this up as a series of singular players. Each one plays fine - but because I have no other control features than those on each video, someone can start all the videos and they would play at same time. Obviously would prefer to have one stop when someone clicks on another. I am thinking that this could be accomplished with some javascript that would "listen" for someone to click on another video and then stop the one prior - but I am not sure where to begin. Here is what I have so far (just using two videos as an example).

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 small-12 columns">        
        <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2">
          <li>
             <p><strong>DATE - TITLE</strong></p>
             <div class="video-player">
                <div class="video-tree">
                  <video id="myVideo8" poster="myFirstSplashImage.png" controls>
                  <source src="myFirstVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
                  </video>
                </div> <!-- end video-tree -->
            </div><!-- end video-player -->
        </li>
        <li>
         <p><strong>DATE - TITLE</strong></p>
           <div class="video-player">
            <div class="video-tree">
                <video id="myVideo8" poster="mySecondSplashImage.png" controls>
                  <source src="myFirstVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
                 </video>
            </div> <!-- end video-tree -->
          </div><!-- end video-player -->
         </li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- end columns -->
 </div> <!-- end row -->
```

At the close of the page, I have started out with this javascript but I'm uncertain what to listen for and I think I need to create some sort of array to first load all the video ids.

```
<script>
    var vid=document.getElementById('??');
```

Then I think I need to listen for an event and call my function
        vid.addEventListener("clicked?", resetVideo, true);

```
    function resetVideo() {
    // stop the playing video and start the new one? Or do I just need to stop the prior one as the "clicked" should already be starting the new one?
    this.load()
    }   
</script>
```

If anyone can just give me a hint and point me in the right direction that will be great. I don't expect anyone to code this for me - I really want to understand and learn and do this. Thanks!

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) are your events to listen for. I would get a [collection of video elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), iterate through them and add a listener for each. To handle the event, iterate through the video elements and pause all of them except for the video that the user clicked 'play' on.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will give this a try and post back what I discover. Thanks again!!